# styling and formatting text background and layout

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using trying to make a dating app-style flutter program. I want to display 5 keywords over the top of the user's image as little rounded edge overlays. Currently, the list of words is 1. Expanding off of the profile image and 2. The words are spaced too close together, 3. The background color blocks of the keywords are like sharp rectangles, I want them to be like rounded rectangles. I hope that makes sense.

Thank you!

```
   Widget buildKeywords() => Container(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(width: 8),
                Text(
                  'Keyword 1',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: AppTheme.ndsnPink),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Keyword 2',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: AppTheme.ndsnPink),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Keyword 3',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: AppTheme.ndsnPink),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Keyword 4',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: AppTheme.ndsnPink),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Keyword 5',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white, backgroundColor: AppTheme.ndsnPink),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have 3 questions:

> "1. expanding off of the profile image"

If you want to make it scroll, wrap the `Row` with a `SingleChildScrollView`, like so:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Row( /* ... */ ),
)
```

Or if you want them to automatically go into a new line, use `Wrap` widget instead of `Row` widget.

> "2. the words are spaced too close together"

You can either wrap your `Text` widgets with `Padding` widgets, or insert some `SizedBox(width: 4)` widgets in between those texts.

> "3. The background colour blocks of the keywords are like sharp rectangles, I want them to be like rounded rectangles."

To round them, use `ClipRRect`, or use the `Chip` widget.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Chip is what you need. Link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Chip-class.html

If you need more than 5 items or those items to be horizontally aligned, replace the Wrap with a ListView.

```
 Widget buildKeywords() => Container(
            child: Wrap(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(width: 8),
                Chip(
                  side:BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink,
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                  label: Text(
                  'Keyword 1',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                Chip(
                  side:BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink,
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                  label: Text(
                  'Keyword 2',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
                Chip(
                  side:BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink,
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                  label:Text(
                  'Keyword 3',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                )
                ,
                Chip(
                  side:BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink,
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                  label: Text(
                  'Keyword 4',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                )
                ,
                Chip(
                  side:BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.pink,
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                  label: Text(
                  'Keyword 5',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                )               
              ],
            ),
          );
```